# loading testing from a one ec2 linux/ubuntu instance to another ec2 linux/ubuntu instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, performance

I wanna run a load/stress testing on ubuntu ec2 small instance. I could have done it using Jmeter from my laptop itself, but that would actually consume lot of bandwidth and also I feel I cant get the real the performance and stress statics.

I am looking for a either a method or a app, similar to jmeter which would bang my another ec2 ubuntu instance and I could access the load/stress it takes.

Kindly suggest me any tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home)
This would probably be my preference - Some of its options include the number of simultaneous requests, delay between requests, and number of times each user should make a request. Most importantly though, it lets you specify a URL list which it can be setup to access at random - this will provide a more realistic test than simply hitting the same URL multiple times.

[ApacheBench (ab)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)
This is part of the httpd-tools package (i.e. you don't need to install all of Apache if it isn't your web server of choice). It lets you specify number of concurrent users and total requests - but only accesses a single URL. It provides a good breakdown of time per-request.

[httperf](http://code.google.com/p/httperf/) is another choice - it tends to be better for lower concurrency tests.

If you are testing between instances you may want to have a baseline bandwidth number - [iPerf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) should be able to provide that.

Keep in mind that only bandwidth in the same availability zone is not charged.